# Zoom softly into the center of a D3 map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

I have a create an **[interactive map](http://arda-maps.org/ages/first)**. This map can be zoomed via buttons. These buttons already work but I don't like the current style. It does not feel UX-friendly when by clicking the button the map is shaking a bit. I would like to zoom into the center of the map softly instead.

[image]

Here zoom-in **code** on the **button**:

```
d3.select('#zoomplusbutton').on('click', function () {
    ardamap.zoomByFactor(1.3);
});
```

And here the **function code** with the strange zooming:

```
zoomByFactor: function (factor) {
                d3.event.preventDefault();
                var scale = zoom.scale();
                var extent = zoom.scaleExtent();
                var newScale = scale * factor;
                if (extent[0] <= newScale && newScale <= extent[1]) {
                    var t = zoom.translate();
                    var c = [width / 2, height / 2];
                    zoom
                        .scale(newScale)
                        .translate([c[0] + (t[0] - c[0]) / scale * newScale, c[1] + (t[1] - c[1]) / scale * newScale])
                        .event(g.transition());
                }
            }
```

I really don't know anymore where I got this zooming code from.

So how can I really zoom to the center of the map softly? Feel free to change the JS-code on the website.

Comment: can you not put a duration on the transition ?

Comment: Usually I can. But I don't really know if putting a duration here would solve all the other issues. As I said I dont know where I have this code from. Too long ago.

Comment: well thats no help then if you dont know your code lol how are you going to solve something when you forgotten what it involves :/

Comment: i think its laggy because of all the images you have. ive taken a look at your previous questions and noticed that your loading large files in thats probably why your getting the jittery effect

Comment: Well but try to zoom via the mousewheel and see *rough* to *smooth*. This is how I want to have it. So it is actually possible. Even with my images.

Comment: its like your translating it up abit before scaling. maybe your zoom function is off

Comment: How do you mean with the function is off? And I know overall what the code is doing in detail for sure, I just don't know where I got it from.

Comment: by 'off' i mean something wrong with it. When i click to zoom on your application it doesnt zoom in the center straight away its as if it translates up slightly before scaling the svg

Comment: Yes indeed that's my issue ;) But this is resulted by this function. So overall I just need somehow to find the center of the current view and then the zooming is trivial.Anyway a translate is needed because of the center zooming. Any idea on how to solve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours now figured out a 'OK' solution. It's **not** perfectly the center but at the end without shaking and any other bad behaviour:

```
zoomButton: function (zoom_in) {
            var scale = zoom.scale(),
                extent = zoom.scaleExtent(),
                translate = zoom.translate(),
                x = translate[0], y = translate[1],
                factor = zoom_in ? 1.3 : 1/1.3,
                target_scale = scale * factor;
            if (target_scale === extent[0] || target_scale === extent[1] || target_scale > extent[1] || target_scale < extent[0]) { return false; }
            var clamped_target_scale = Math.max(extent[0], Math.min(extent[1], target_scale));
            if (clamped_target_scale != target_scale){
                target_scale = clamped_target_scale;
                factor = target_scale / scale;
            }
            x = (x - center[0]) * factor + center[0];
            y = (y - center[1]) * factor + center[1];
            if (zoom_in){
                x = x - 500;
            }else{
                x = x + 500;
            }
            d3.transition().duration(450).tween("zoom", function () {
                var interpolate_scale = d3.interpolate(scale, target_scale),
                    interpolate_trans = d3.interpolate(translate, [x,y]);
                return function (t) {
                    zoom.scale(interpolate_scale(t))
                        .translate(interpolate_trans(t));
                    ardamap.zoomedButton();
                };
            });
        }
```

These calculations work pretty well. And here the two button raising events:

```
d3.select('#zoomplusbutton').on('click', function(){
    ardamap.zoomButton(true);
});
d3.select('#zoomminusbutton').on('click', function () {
    ardamap.zoomButton(false);
});
```

You can find the code update on arda-maps.org as well. If you have I fix for really going to the center of the current map, feel free to edit my answer. I'm still interested in improving this!